# Regex match pattern into a characters string OR another pattern in the same characters string

Tags: javascript, regex, google-tag-manager

I need your help for my Google Tag Manager settings.

I'd like a trigger to fire if an item number from a list is recognized in a characters string.

Let's give an example. My item list:

```
11310
11311
11312
11313
```

If the DOM Element contains `11310` OR `11311` 0R `11312` OR `11313` into a characters string, then the trigger should fire.

Could you please help to create the relevant RegEx?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```js
function match(str){
    return str.match(/^1131[0-3]$/) != null;
}

console.log(match('11310'));
console.log(match('11311'));
console.log(match('11312'));
console.log(match('11313'));
console.log(match('11314'));
```